# Dynamically control the output voltage of a 60V DC input

Tags: arduino-mega, digital, voltage, voltage-divider

I am hoping to control a 60V DC input source dynamically using my Arduino so that the output voltage could vary between 0v to 60v. At first i was looking into digital potential meter, however I couldn't find any digital pot that can support 60V DC input voltage. 
I have came across a few articles with similar situation (but theirs with lower voltage).

Could anyone suggest any solution to my problem? 
Thanks. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use a 5V digital pot, or a 5V DAC. Then feed that through an OpAmp to convert the 0-5V to a 0-60V output.

Comment: @Gerben could you guide me on how to design /which kind of opAmp that can step up from 5v to 60v? I tried googling but none of them step up from 5 to 60. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try asking at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ . This isn't really my area of expertise.

Comment: Does your voltage source just have to output a voltage or does it need to drive any significant current (i.e. do you want to use it as a power supply)? BTW please be careful with these relatively high voltages. They can easily damage your Arduino and can be very unpleasant to touch.

Comment: @StarCat thank you for your comment, i am looking at a current around/less than 0.1 A

Answer (score -1):

Try ZMPT101B. Easy to use and very cheap

[Active Single Phase Voltage Transformer Module AC Output Voltage Sensor for Arduino Mega ZMPT101B 2mA](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000193055897.html?src)

Comment: Can this be used to control output voltage real time?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This module does not do what @jetjetboi wants. I would also advise against buying a random module off aliexpress with no documentation.